# Android EGL-ERROR: max aquired buffer count reached

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview, gpu

I've got an issue with my android app (target sdk 17-19) that displays a webview with several videos and images (1080p and 720p) in a loop of about 3 minutes.

The app works fine for days on different hardware, but my CloudnetGo CR11/s (last firmware with Android 4.2.2) with Rockchip RK3188 chipset and Quad-Core Mali-400 GPU crashes after about 3-6 hours with following logcat entries. I tried different combinations of video codecs and containers - without success.

```
EGL-ERROR: mali_image* _egl_android_map_native_buffer_rgb(android_native_buffer_t*):317: unable to allocate memory for EGLImage backed by CPU (1280 x 720)

SurfaceTexture: [unnamed-18923-504] error creating EGLImage: 0x3003

SurfaceTexture: [unnamed-18923-504] updateTexImage: acquire failed: Unknown error (-2147483648)

BufferQueue: [unnamed-18923-504] acquireBuffer: max aquired buffer count reached: 2 (max=1)

SurfaceTexture: [unnamed-18923-504] updateTexImage: acquire failed: Function not implemented (-38)
```

I hope somebody can help because i don't find any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that error from a malicious firmware, at least the android version matches. An actual firmware should not have the issue since its been nearly one year.